# Angularjs moving back in previous page maintain same state

Tags: angularjs

I have two pages. One has calendar details for each person and the other contains personal details. When the user selects a particular date, he can see all persons specific to that date. After selecting a person I show the personal details. Now, when the user clicks on the back button, I want it so that he can see the same state of calendar details. I am not able to maintain the previous state after the redirect. As I understand it, I could keep the data in the `$rootScope` and access it from there but is there any easier way.

Comment: Maybe u need to try angular service.

Comment: As Vicky said - check out angular service (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Services are singleton, so in each controller it's the same object and you can store info in is. Of course, if you don't reload page

Answer (score 0):

Try using history similar to the below:

```
element.on('click', function() {
     $window.history.back();
 });
```

element being the button you use to redirect the user back to the calendar.

Hope this helps.